# Is $\|X-A\|_{op}\|A^{-1}\|_{op} < 1$ for any $X \in \Omega$ and for any fixed $A \in \Omega$?

Tags: metric-spaces, operator-theory

> Is $\|X-A\|_{op}\|A^{-1}\|_{op} < 1$ for any $X \in \Omega$ and for any fixed $A \in \Omega$?
>
> Where $\Omega$ denotes the space of all linear operators on $\mathbb R^n$.

Here's what I have done:

Suppose $\|X-A\|=\beta$ and $\|A^{-1}\|=\frac {1} {\alpha}$. Then for any $y \in \mathbb R^n$, $\alpha\|y\| = \alpha \|A^{-1}Ay\| \leq \|Ay\| \leq \|(A-X)y\|+\|Xy\| \leq \|A-X\|_{op}\|y\|+\|Xy\|$ $=\beta\|y\| + \|Xy\|$ $\implies$ $(\alpha-\beta)\|y\| \leq \|Xy\|$. Since $y \in \mathbb R^n$ is completely arbitrarily taken so if we take $X^{-1}y$ in place $y$ in the previous inequality it holds. Hence $(\alpha-\beta)\|X^{-1}y\| \leq \|y\|$. This shows that $\|X^{-1}\|_{op} \leq (\alpha - \beta)^{-1}$. Since $\|X^{-1}\|_{op} > 0$ $\implies$ $\alpha > \beta$.  i.e. $\|X-A\|_{op}\|A^{-1}\|_{op} < 1$. Which proves the result.

Is it correct at all? If it is correct then it follows that whatever $X \in \Omega$ we take, $X$ belongs to the open ball centered at $A$ and radius $\alpha$. i.e. $B(A,\alpha) = \Omega$. Since $A \in \Omega$ can be fixed arbitrarily so it follows that $\Omega$ can be viewed as an open ball centered at any of it's points with some certain radius.I wonder how can can it be possible? I don't find any such example in metric space so far other than the discrete metric space where an open ball can be centered at any of it's points with some certain radius. I think I have done some serious mistake here. Though inspite of my effort I am unable to find my mistake. Please help me in this regard.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, why is $\alpha-\beta>0$? You need this already when you divide by this quantity to preserver the sense of the inequality. Also, you want $A$ invertible and not arbitrary?

Comment: Yeah! You are right. Now I have understood where my fault was. Thank you very much @max_zorn.